# External Monitor not working. HP ELITEBOOK G2 840 CORE I5 5TH GEN

Tags: 23.04, 23.10

Peace be upon you.

I have this problem when I log to my laptop the monitor doesn't work but when I remove the display adapter separate the adapter from HDMI cable the plug everything together it works. I didn't have this problem before.

Any idea how to fix it also i have txt message when booting I enabled vtx but some error still appear.